# how to open widget from app?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, widget

i want to open google sound search widget from my application. i can open google app by using intent

```
  Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox");
            if (launchIntent != null) {
                startActivity(launchIntent);
            }
```

but i don't want to open google app , but i want to open a widget of google app

i tried this

```
  Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.apps.gsa.soundsearchwidget.IntentWidgetProvider");
            if (launchIntent != null) {
                startActivity(launchIntent);//null pointer check in case package name was not found
            }
```

but its not opening the widget , how can i do that ??

here is the PackageName and ActivityName

```
PackageName    = com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox
ActivityName   = com.google.android.apps.gsa.soundsearchwidget.IntentWidgetProvider
```

I think, i should open the activity of google app, if so how can open that?

Comment: You cannot start an app widget. App widgets are for use by the home screen, Android 4.x lockscreens, and other apps that implement an `AppWidgetHost`.

Comment: how to open an activity then ?

Comment: Call `startActivity()`. `IntentWidgetProvider` would not appear to be an activity. That appears to be a `BroadcastReceiver`.